# What are row-wise and column-wise proportions?

Tags: r, conditional-probability, proportion

I want to know the principle of row-wise proportion and column-wise proportion.  Could anyone tell me the difference between them? I also find that the result of R's `prop.test()` is also different from them.  For example,

```
prop.table(table(train$Sex, train$Survived)) 
prop.table(table(train$Sex, train$Survived),1)

# Row-wise proportions: 
prop.table(table(<var_1>, <var_2>),1)
# Column-wise proportions: 
prop.table(table(<var_1>, <var_2>),2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example mentions "sex" and "survived", so let's say you are working with data from the [sinking of the Titanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinking_of_the_RMS_Titanic).

```
data(titanic)
tab = margin.table(Titanic, margin=c(2,4))
tab
#         Survived
# Sex        No  Yes
#   Male   1364  367
#   Female  126  344
```

One way to examine this table is just to print the numbers above.  But you may want to estimate the probability that an observation (here a passenger) would be in some given cell.  The different proportions are estimates of different probabilities.  R's [?prop.table(](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/prop.table.html)) will give you the proportion of the observations in each cell as a function of the sum of the whole table (because you didn't specify the `margin` argument).  Think of tossing a coin onto a sheet of paper that has four boxes, such that the coin could land on any of them.  However, the boxes could differ in size, or be closer, or more in line with your arm, etc., so that some might be more likely than others.  In this situation, you might want to know what the probability the coin will land in the different boxes is.

```
prop.table(tab)
#         Survived
# Sex              No        Yes
#   Male   0.61971831 0.16674239
#   Female 0.05724671 0.15629259
```

However, we don't necessarily think of people as being randomly one sex or the other.  We usually think of sex as pre-existing, in a way that survival is not.  Thus, you may want to know the probability that a passenger will survive, given that they are male or female.  These are [conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).  The conditional proportions computed from the table are estimates of those conditional probabilities.  Because sex is listed in the rows of this table, we need the  row-wise proportions specifically.  These are computed by dividing each count by the sum of the counts for its row.

```
prop.table(tab, margin=1)
#         Survived
# Sex             No       Yes
#   Male   0.7879838 0.2120162
#   Female 0.2680851 0.7319149
tab[1,]/sum(tab[1,])
#        No       Yes 
# 0.7879838 0.2120162 
tab[2,]/sum(tab[2,])
#        No       Yes 
# 0.2680851 0.7319149
```

Alternatively, you might be interested in the perspective of those who are investigating the disaster after the Carpathia has delivered the survivors to New York.  They would have noticed many more women (and children) than men.  They could have wanted to estimate the probability that a survivor (or a victim) would be male or female.  These are again conditional probabilities, and are estimated by the conditional proportions.  Because the survival status is listed in the columns, you need column-wise proportions.  They are computed by dividing each count by the sum of the counts for its column.

```
prop.table(tab, margin=2)
#         Survived
# Sex              No        Yes
#   Male   0.91543624 0.51617440
#   Female 0.08456376 0.48382560
t(t(tab[,1]/sum(tab[,1])))
#              [,1]
# Male   0.91543624
# Female 0.08456376    
t(t(tab[,2]/sum(tab[,2])))
#             [,1]
# Male   0.5161744
# Female 0.4838256
```

All of the above are just estimates.  You could want to conduct a [hypothesis test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) of whether the conditional probabilities that someone died are the same from one row (column) to the other.  That's what R's [?prop.test()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/prop.test.html) does.

```
prop.test(tab)
# 
#   2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction
# 
# data:  tab
# X-squared = 454.5, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.4741109 0.5656866
# sample estimates:
#    prop 1    prop 2 
# 0.7879838 0.2680851
```

Note that prop 1 and 2 listed at the bottom of the results *are* the same as the conditional proportions for dying returned by `prop.table(tab, margin=1)` above.